# rospy equivalent of ROS_*_NAMED

Tags: ros, rospy, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came across [a blog post about modifying the settings for logging](http://dav.ee/blog/notes/archives/898). In the post, the `ROS_WARN_NAMED` function was mentioned. I hadn't seen that before and thought that it would be useful if there's a `rospy` equivalent. I tried searching for it, but didn't find anything (which makes me believe that this doesn't exist for `rospy`).

Is there a `rospy` equivalent of the `ROS_*_NAMED` family of logging functions? Any release of ROS will do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275295/rospy-equivalent-of-ros_*_named/) by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6155 on 2017-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no convenience wrappers for this afaik (so no `rospy.loginfo_named(..)` or similar), but `rospy` does support named loggers since [ros/ros_comm#948](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/948).

They would be used like so (taken from the unit test):

```
rospy.loginfo("test child logger 1", logger_name="log1")
```

Note: this is only available on Lunar <del>and Kinetic (backported in [ros/ros_comm#1205](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1205))</del> not on Kinetic ("new feature, not backported").

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1